# Software to mix Pandora stream with my MP3 library

Tags: windows, macos, ipod-touch, audio-streaming, mixing

Title basically says it all, but let me explain the situation a little more...

I'm helping a family member with the music at her wedding this summer. I'd like to be able to set up a few playlists from e.g. my own MP3 collection and then need a (preferably) software solution that would allow me to mix/switch between playing music from my custom playlists and from my Pandora account.

I know I could accomplish this by say, starting a playlist on my iPod, and then manually switching to the Pandora app, then switching back, etc. What I'd really like it something maybe a little more automated, or at least something that would give smoother transitions between MP3 / Pandora. I'm looking for something that will run on windows (XP, 7), OSX, or an app that will run on an iPod Touch.

Free is the best, but I wouldn't mind paying a reasonable price for the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you localize the stream (by downloading the music that would have streamed), you can mix all you want, even on the fly.

The **really** cheap way to do this is:

1. Take a pen and paper, write down the names of the music/songs that play on your Pandora stream.
2. Go to your local library, and find the music on CDs, and rip them to your computer/iPod. (You can also ask friends if they have copies of the music.)
3. Put all the music you may want into one large folder, and familiarize yourself with it, so you can quickly mix on the fly.
4. Enjoy the wedding.

Comment: Yes, this is of course an option. The point of my question though was to find a solution whereby I could just _let Pandora play_ whatever it chooses, in my specific genre / mix of stations. I don't necessarily have a list of songs I want off of Pandora, nor do I have a whole lot of time to generate that list.

Comment: @kaveman: you'd want to play a song, without knowing what it is, at a WEDDING?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but yes I'm hoping to create a nice mix of Pandora stations and letting it do most of the playlisting work.